# Table Header not displaying text in second page while generating PDF in v 9.1.20

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, flying-saucer

We are using latest version of flying saucer v 9.1.20 , In that the table header is displaying correctly on first page with text , but **it seems to be broken in remaining pages, header is repeated but the text is not visible.**

We have also used property **-fs-table-paginate: paginate** in our code , but still the **header text appears to be blank in pages**

We have also tried with previous versions, and it works till version 9.1.15. Have anyone faced this issue, kindly let us know the solution for this.

Have also attached the screen shots of sample PDF and code that we have used.

**Sample Code :**

```html
<style>
table {
  -fs-table-paginate: paginate;
}
</style>

<table style="width:20%;" border="1">
  <thead style="background: #222; color: #fff;">
    <tr>
      <td>Header 1</td>
      <td>Header 2</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>test html</td>
      <td>test html</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce your issue. In my test, the header is fine on both pages with flying-saucer 9.1.20.

Comment: obourgain Thank you for your reply. Can you help us with any sample code that worked and jar that you have used for generating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me with version 9.1.20 of flying-saucer.

The jar was added through maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
    <artifactId>flying-saucer-pdf</artifactId>
    <version>9.1.20</version>
</dependency>
```

**Maven dependencies**

```
[INFO] ------------------------< org.example:SO-temp >------------------------
[INFO] Building SO-temp 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:list (default-cli) @ SO-temp ---
[INFO]
[INFO] The following files have been resolved:
[INFO]    org.bouncycastle:bctsp-jdk14:jar:1.46:compile
[INFO]    org.xhtmlrenderer:flying-saucer-pdf:jar:9.1.20:compile
[INFO]    org.xhtmlrenderer:flying-saucer-core:jar:9.1.20:compile
[INFO]    com.lowagie:itext:jar:2.1.7:compile
[INFO]    org.bouncycastle:bcmail-jdk14:jar:1.64:compile
[INFO]    org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk14:jar:1.64:compile
[INFO]    org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk14:jar:1.64:compile
```

**Java part**

```
public class SO {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String html = String.join("\n", Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("so.html"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("so.pdf"));
        renderer.setDocumentFromString(html);
        renderer.layout();
        renderer.createPDF(out);
        out.close();
    }
}
```

**HTML Part**

```
<html>
<head>
    <style  type="text/css">
        table {-fs-table-paginate: paginate;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<table style="width:20%;" border="1">
    <thead style="background: #222; color: #fff;">
    <tr><td>Header 1</td><td>Header 2</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>
    <tr><td>test html</td><td>test html</td></tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obourgain Thanks for your help. We were using jar for flying saucer downloaded for different source, which had caused this problem. Now using the appropriate jar it seems to be working fine.